# Keras layer.set_weights doesn't modify the layer. Why?

Tags: keras

When I initialize and load weights to a model I get a 67% accuracy for the output.

```py
model.load_weights(path+'results/finetune_train_last_layer.h5')  
batches = model.get_batches(path, shuffle=False, batch_size=128, class_mode=None)
preds = model.predict_generator(batches, batches.nb_sample)
matches = 0
for guess, ans in zip(np.argmax(preds, axis=1), batches.classes):
    if guess == ans:
        matches += 1
print('%s/%s' % (matches, len(batches.classes)))

532/792
```

The layers are correctly loaded. This is the same accuracy I got on my last round of training for these weights before I saved them.

However, when I try to make a new model with identical layers to the last layers in `model` and copy the weights, they don't have the same weights. How is this possible?

```py
no_drop_model = Sequential([
    MaxPooling2D(input_shape=(512, 14, 14)),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.),
    Dense(4096, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.),
    Dense(120, activation='softmax')
])
for ndl, fcl in zip(no_drop_model.layers, model.layers[31:]):
    print(type(ndl), type(fcl))
    ndl.set_weights(fcl.get_weights())
    if ndl.get_weights():
        print(np.array_equiv(ndl.get_weights(), fcl.get_weights()))
```

Output:

```
(<class 'keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D'>, <class 'keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D'>)
(<class 'keras.layers.core.Flatten'>, <class 'keras.layers.core.Flatten'>)
(<class 'keras.layers.core.Dense'>, <class 'keras.layers.core.Dense'>)
False
(<class 'keras.layers.core.Dropout'>, <class 'keras.layers.core.Dropout'>)
(<class 'keras.layers.core.Dense'>, <class 'keras.layers.core.Dense'>)
False
(<class 'keras.layers.core.Dropout'>, <class 'keras.layers.core.Dropout'>)
(<class 'keras.layers.core.Dense'>, <class 'keras.layers.core.Dense'>)
False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `model.get_weights()` is a list of numpy arrays not a single array. You should compare the weights like this:

```py
def create_model():
    i = Input((2,))
    o = Dense(3)(i)
    return Model(i, o)

model1 = create_model()
model2 = create_model()

for w1, w2 in zip(model1.get_weights(), model2.get_weights()):
    print(np.array_equiv(w1, w2))

model2.set_weights(model1.get_weights())
print 'Weights after:'
for w1, w2 in zip(model1.get_weights(), model2.get_weights()):
    print(np.array_equiv(w1, w2))
```

This will produce the following output:

```
False
True
Weights after:
True
True
```

The second element in the weight list corresponds to bias values which are initialized to zero, so the values are the same prior to copying weights.

Comment: Nice! Much cleaner to do it this way also. Thanks for the response.